# Como manejar funciones usando un array o lista de clases en TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular6

estoy tratando de estructurar una función en Angular(TypeScript) que me permita obtener el registro de una lista de items o elementos de un array, lo único que no entiendo es como manejar instancias de clases o asignación de propiedades de acuerdo a un filtro.Tengo el sig. código:

```
 export class AppComponent {
 diassemana:Array<semana>= [{numero:1,nombre:"lunes",actividad:"Correr"}, 
{numero:2,nombre:"martes",actividad:"Bailar"}, 
{numero:3,nombre:"miercoles",actividad:"Musica"}, 
{numero:4,nombre:"jueves",actividad:"Bicicleta"}]
...

asignaactividad(_numero){
    let tarea:semana={};/*new semana(1,"x","x");*/
    tarea= this.diassemana.filter(work => work.numero == _numero);
    return tarea.actividad;
    }
}
class semana {
  constructor(_numero, _nombre, _actividad) {
    this.numero = _numero;
    this.nombre = _nombre;
    this.actividad=_actividad;
  }
numero:number;
nombre:string;
actividad:string;
}
```

Ahí me marca el sig. error en mi variable tarea:

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'semana':

aquí trato d aplicar find y filter pero no me accede a las propiedades

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
    detallelibro:Array<Object>;
    libroId:number;
    libroSeleccionado:Object;
    constructor(private ruta:ActivatedRoute) {
        this.detallelibro=[ {id:1,titulo:"POESIAS",autor:"PABLO NERUDA"}]
     }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ruta.params.subscribe(params =>{ /*...*/})
    }
    filtroPorID(detallelibro){
        detallelibro.id=this;
        alert('funcionPorid this:'+detallelibro.id);
        return detallelibro.id=this;
    }
    encontrarLibro(){
        alert(this.detallelibro.find(librobuscado =>librobuscado.id==this.libroId));
        alert('primer findlibro'+ this.detallelibro.filter(librobuscado =>librobuscado.id==this));
        return alert( this.detallelibro.filter(this.filtroPorID, this.libroId)[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por una parte, si quieres hacer

```
let tarea: Semana = {};
```

... debes definir todos los atributos del tipo `semana` como *nullables* (u opcionales)

```
class Semana {
  constructor(_numero, _nombre, _actividad) {
    this.numero = _numero;
    this.nombre = _nombre;
    this.actividad=_actividad;
  }

  numero?: number;
  nombre?: string;
  actividad?: string;
}
```

Y algo no relacionado con tu pregunta, `array.filter(filterFn)` devuelve un `array`, por lo que deberías seleccionar el primer elemento

```
// ...
tarea = this.diassemana.filter(work => work.numero == _numero)[0];
return tarea.actividad;
```

`Array` tiene una función precisamente para este propósito, `find`

```
tarea = this.diassemana.find(work => work.numero == _numero);
```

Y te sugiero que tengas en cuenta el escenario donde no encuentres ningún elemento con dicho filtro, ya que `tarea.actividad` lanzaría una excepción.

```
tarea = this.diassemana.find(work => work.numero == _numero);
if (tarea) return tarea.actividad;

// Aquí pones el código en caso de que no exista ninguna tarea
```

Espero que sirva.

**RE: uso de `filter`**

El compilador se queja al intentar acceder a la propiedad `id` dado que tu `array` es de tipo `Object`.
Siempre hay que evitar el uso del tipo `Object`. Si no se sabe qué estructura tiene un objeto en concreto, debe usarse `any` (como último recurso).
Este no es tu caso, dado que sabes perfectamente qué estructura tienen los objetos contenidos en tu `array`.

```
interface DetalleLibro {
    id: number;
    titulo: string;
    autor: string;
}

export class DetallesComponent implements OnInit {
   // He cambiado el nombre de la propiedad para que tenga más sentido   
   detalles: DetalleLibro[];

   // libroSeleccionado será también de tipo DetalleLibro
   // pero también puede ser undefined, si es que no hay ninguno seleccionado
   libroSeleccionado: DetalleLibro | undefined;

   // ...
}
```

Haciendo este cambio, tu implementación deberá cambiar mucho, también. Por ejemplo

```
// Dado que filtroPorID se usa en array.prototype.filter, debe retornar un
// boolean. El retorno de la función es un number,
// que Javascript hará un type coerce a false (en caso de 0) o a true (=! 0)
filtroPorID(detalleLibro: DetalleLibro) {
   detalleLibro.id = this;

   // En este caso, el cual también dará error
   // te "funciona" por mera casualidad.
   // Dado que has asignado anteriormente detalleLibro a this
   // el resultado de la asignación será this, de nuevo (el valor antiguo).
   return detalleLibro.id = this;
}
```

Bueno, en cualquier caso te sugiero que veas cómo deberías refactorizar el código para usar el nuevo tipo. Y te podría servir intentarlo por ti mismo antes de abrir cualquier otra pregunta en la comunidad.

De nuevo, espero que sirva. Y si tienes cualquier duda después de intentarlo, por supuesto abre otra pregunta. Encantado la solucionaré, o cualquier otro miembro de la comunidad.

Creo que la pregunta inicial del *post* está más que solventada.

Comment: excelente aporte amigo @VRoxa